# UISearchBar hides behind UISearchController view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented custom `UISearchBar` and custom `UISearchController`. They both reside inside a `UITableViewController` which is controlled by a `UINavigationController`.

The animation of dismissing the `UISearchBar` should move the `UISearchController` with it but it doesn't it hides the `UISearchBar` behind the `UISearchController` as in the image attached. I couldn't figure out what causes this issue and any idea would be welcome

[image: UISearchBar behind UISearchController]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was caused by calling to `reloadTable` for the hosting table of `UISearchController`. Updating the table after `UISearchController` is dismissed and not beforehand resolves this issue.